# 404 Codeigniter page error when calling method

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, config

I'm having a problem with code igniter, I have the following code (user_stats.php):

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_stats extends MX_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function user_stats() {
        echo "Hello";
    }
    function detect_location() {
        echo "World";
    }   
}
```

If I call the method via the url e.g. http://test/user_stats/detect_location I get the output World, but when I load up http://test/user_stats/user_stats I get an error 404 page. I checked the logs and for some reason the the request was for http://test/user_stats/index (when trying to load http://test/user_stats/user_stats). My htaccess file has the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and config file is configured as:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

Any help resolving this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your Class name is `User_stats` and function name is `user_stats` same. A function name with same class name is treated as construct function. if you remove your `function __construct()` and hit this url `http://test/user_stats/detect_location` you will get output

```
Hello World
```

This case  user_stats is your construct function.
Actually You have two construct function and `function  user_stats` is useless if you keep `function __construct()`. You cannot have two construct function for a class with same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name `user_stats()` to `index()` and open `config/routes.php` file
and add this line in it :

```
$route['user_stats/user_stats'] = "user_stats/index";
```

Note : as @oldlearner said, the function act like a constructor, and it's deprecated in php5.